# Is there a way to use ListView.Builder in a Column without shrinkwrap?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I'm attempting to place a ListView.builder inside a Column that is a peer to a SliverAppBar. Because of this I need to leverage a CustomScrollview and a SliverToBoxAdapter so that the Column can reside inside the CustomScrollView.

This all works fine as long as I set shrinkwrap to true.

But, for performance reasons I do not want to use shrinkwrap (per the official documentation, this is very expensive and negates the performance benefit of having the ListView.Builder lazy load the list items).

The Error is: "***RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded***". This is because the Column has infinite height.

I would like to **not** have to hard code the size of the Columns as this will be a responsive/adaptive scaffold.

My code is below - my question is, has anyone been able to use a Column with a ListView.Builder as a child without using shrinkwrap set to true and without hard coding the height?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestScaffold({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[100],
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      const Text('Title 1'),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          //shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: 3,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                height: 100,
                                width: 100,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      const Text('Title 2'),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          //shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: 3,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                height: 100,
                                width: 100,
                                color: Colors.green,
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SliverFillRemaining` over `Row` while inner widget are using `Expanded`.

```dart
class TestScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestScaffold({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[100],
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverFillRemaining( //this
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      const Text('Title 1'),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          //shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: 3,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                height: 100,
                                width: 100,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      const Text('Title 2'),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          //shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: 3,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                height: 100,
                                width: 100,
                                color: Colors.green,
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I think you will Also like to use [`SliverPersistentHeader`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverPersistentHeader-class.html) for your case.

Comment: Thank you @yeasin-sheikh that works very well! I'll dig into both the SliverFillRemaining and SliverPersistentHeader widgets to better understand them.

Comment: Glad to help, also you can checkout [constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)